# Boost Python Basic function returning int: SIGSEGV

Tags: python, c++, cmake, boost-python

I successfully used Boost Python to write C++ functions with Numpy array arguments.

But I'm struggling with a very basic case: when my function has to return a value. There's no problem until I try to read the `int` returned by my function.

I strongly suspect my setup has something to do with this, but I'm not sure where to begin. I commented my `CMakeLists.txt` to explain how I did setup all the libs.

I tried to play with `return_value_policy` but it seems irrelevant for simple scalar values.

Environment:

- MacOS 11.0.1 (20B50)
- CLion for C++ edition and build
- Pycharm to run Python code, configured using conda environment with Python 3.8
- Boost setup described in `CMakeLists.txt`

C++ code:

```cpp
int testFunction() {
    std::cout << "Test Function 1\n";
    return 1;
}

void testFunction2() {
    std::cout << "Test Function 2\n";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (mylib) {
    np::initialize();
    py::def("test_function", testFunction);
    py::def("test_function_2", testFunction2);
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(mylib_project)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

find_package(PythonInterp 3)
find_package(PythonLibs 3)

# Standard boost installation
# Download boost https://www.boost.org/users/download/ and unzip
# Inside boost dir:
#    ./bootstrap.sh
#    ./b2
#    ./b2 install
# Other (brew / macports) install will have all chances to fail (at the time of writing)


# Components should be found in path with name libboost_NAME.dylib, eg: /usr/local/lib/libboost_numpy38.dylib
# This is additional to standard boost installation
# For both python38 and numpy38 to be produced, you have to:
# - be in the right python environment (conda python 3.8 for example)
# - install numpy: pip install numpy
# - inside boost dir:
#    ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
#    ./b2
#    ./b2 install
find_package(Boost 1.75.0 COMPONENTS python38 numpy38 REQUIRED)

# Python library, will produce a mylib.so file
python_add_module(mylib python-mylib.cpp)

target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(mylib ${PYTHON_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(mylib ${Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(mylib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm then producing a `mylib.so` that I provide to the path of my python code.

Python code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylib.test_function_2()
    result = mylib.test_function()
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
Test Function 2
Test Function 1
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

My naive question is: how to avoid this crash ?

But after some further investigations (see comments) I'd rather ask: how can I proceed to find (and then probably fix) the cause of this issue in my setup ?

Comment: Not reproduced, it works for me with python 3.6.8.

Comment: Thanks @pptaszni, did you reproduce with the same CMakeLists.txt ? Did you alter anything except the python version number ?

Comment: I cut it a bit to remove `sfmt` lib and unnecessary (on my machine) include paths. Like this: https://pastebin.com/hhQK9Hxi And added necessary includes and `using` in cpp to compile.

Comment: Thanks again @pptaszni , that's a good lead :)

Comment: In fact, removing the two hard-coded paths and everything not related to this test  compiled the lib .so file successfully. But I still have the same runtime issue. I guess I can try with other Python versions at compile and/or run time.

Comment: I tested with python 3.7 (compilation and run) and I had the same issue.
I also investigated further my environment to make sure I wasn't using some dusty system python version, I cleared all my `libboost_python*` just to be sure, I checked `project-config.jam` after bootstrapping boost `--with-python` and before running boost's b2 commands... Not a clue what's wrong. I hope my best solution won't be to switch to Linux. I still can try python 3.6.